# Overwrite excel file via VBS + python

Tags: python, excel, vbscript

I have a function that should create a VBScript and save (overwrite) the Excel file, specified in this script with a password on modifying.

The function:

```
    def setPassword(self, excel_file_path, password):
    """Locks excel file with password. Modification allowed only when password is entered"""

    excel_file_path = Path(excel_file_path)

    vbs_script = \
    f"""' Save with password required upon opening

    Set excel_object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set workbook = excel_object.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="{excel_file_path}", ReadOnly:=False, Notify:=False)

    excel_object.DisplayAlerts = False
    excel_object.Visible = False

    workbook.SaveAs "{excel_file_path}",,, "{password}"

    excel_object.Application.Quit
    """

    # write
    vbs_script_path = excel_file_path.parent.joinpath("set_password.vbs")
    with open(vbs_script_path, "w") as file:
        file.write(vbs_script)

    # execute
    result = subprocess.Popen(['cscript.exe', str(vbs_script_path)], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

 
    output, err = result.communicate()
    res = {
        "result": output.decode(encoding='cp866'),
        "err": self._errMessage(err.decode(encoding='cp866'))
    }

    # remove
    vbs_script_path.unlink()

    return res
```

The issue is that on my PC it does it correctly. However, if I run it on my work PC, the VBS throws an exception that it can't access the file when trying to save it.

If I use a different name to save the file with password, it works just fine.
Sure, I could save the file with a different name, delete the initial file and then rename the new file. But it is a duck tape and I want a good solution.

PS
I saw information that it is impossible to overwrite the file this way. But since it works on one computer, I suppose there should be a way to make it work on another.

PPS
Inserting this    `XlSaveConflictResolution`    argument into the save func didn't help as well

What is wrong with this VBS and how to make it work properly?

Comment: Since you don't seem to like ducttape, why can't you access the excel API from Python? Creating a .vbs file to do part of your logic seems very much a ducttape solution to me.

Comment: I failed to find a proper way to secure the file from excel api. There are ways to secure sheets or cells, but no way to secure the entire file from modifying with password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by saving the file under a new name, then deleting the initial file and renaming the new file with the initial name.
For example, I have a file named foo.xlsx. I run the script and save the processed file as foe.xlsx. Then I delete foo.xlsx with os.`os.unlink()`. Finally, I rename the foe.xlsx back to foo.xlsx with `os.rename()`

Hope one day this helps someone